# Is there a way to target a particular topic subscriber with brokered messaging in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

**First my specific question**

Suppose I have 3 subscribers to a topic, but I only want to target a specific subscriber; can this be done?

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

Subscribers listening to topics will be processing messages, which may include database access (and databases may temporarily be down).  When things go wrong, I'd like to be able to reprocess at a later time.

I know that we can use Defer() to process later, however it requires you to save the message id.  Clearly if the database is down I can't save there, so I'd have to save to another datastore if I want to persist.

If that "other datastore" is service bus, then it seems like I'd have to create topics for each of my subscribers, which seems a bit hard to manage.  My plan is to send failed requests to the topic's dead letter queue.  A scheduled task will periodically come by and take messages off of the DLQ for each topic and try to process.  If it fails again, I'd like to resubmit the message and increment an "AttemptedTries" counter, which is part of the message itself.  I'd like it if I could target only the relevant subscribers so that topic subscribers that didn't have issues don't have to process (I could probably add a filter or something if this capability is not available to accomplish similar).

After attempts >= maxattempts, I'd send the message to a universal "graveyard" (not topic specific) where a programmer could decide what to do with the messages.

Is this a good way of handling it?  Does ASB have some of this built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send a message to a specific subscriber, but you can sort of "target it" by stamping your messages with a header/value that specific subscriber filter by.

Now to your scenario - I **HIGHLY** recommend not to use messaging as a storage. An empty queue is a happy queue. And definitely not to use DLQ for that purpose either. It has a designated role and should be used for that.

I would suggest to look into deferral of your messages, and using an atomic operation (ASB transaction) you could simply generate a new message and enqueue it for a future processing if you don't want to deal with a message sequence number. This will also eliminate need in the additional scheduled task and unnecessary complexity when dealing with DLQs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The reason I wanted to use the DLQ was because they are private to each subscriber.  With your suggestion I'd generate a new message and "taget" it so that other topic subscribers don't get affected.  Is that accurate?

Comment: The idea is to receive the message within a transaction where you'd defer the incoming message along with sending a new message with the original message sequence number, setting enqueue time on it to whatever the backoff period you're interested in. That way, when the incoming message is completed and outgoing "delayed" message is sent out, they either both succeed or fail. When you receive the "delayed" message, you fetch your original message by sequence number, and retry. You can still have the custom counter if you'd like to.

Comment: You can also try abstractions over your transport, such as MassTransit and NServiceBus (https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/configure-delayed-retries). They have this sort of feature OOTB.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with using DLQ the way you described. In fact, that's what DLQ is (partially) for:

> The purpose of the dead-letter queue is to hold messages that cannot be delivered to any receiver, or simply messages that could not be processed. Messages can then be removed from the DLQ and inspected. An application might, with help of an operator, correct issues and resubmit the message, log the fact that there was an error, and/or take corrective action.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues

Regarding filters: ASB provides various subscription filters (SQL filter being the most flexible), so you can use them to match message (based on meta data, etc) to the subscriber.

If you go with the filters, consider using single error queue (you called it a graveyard) where all failed messages go. IMO it might be simpler to monitor, inspect and re-process things from one place, rather than dealing with a zillion of DLQ's. In this scenario, a failed message will need to be marked with something like a subscription name (the failed one), so that when it's resent, only that one will try to process.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the mix, I'll add what I discovered.  You can address specific subscribers via the "To" property of the BrokeredMessage.

The subscriber will require a filter (not sure why this isn't automatic); you can use the CorrelationFilter e.g

```
var filter = new CorrelationFilter {To="mySubscriber"};
```

or, in my case I was looking for "send me all messages addressed directly to me OR for all subscribers.  I accomplished this via the SqlFilter,

```
 new SqlFilter($"sys.To IS NULL OR sys.To = '{_subscriptionName}'")
```

Note the use of "sys" since "To" is a property of BrokeredMessage.

Comment: Small clarification you don't really address a subscriber with the "To" property, but rather tag a message. You could use in the same manner a standard property such as "Label" and have the same result. Reason why "To" is not automatic, is because it's a logical "To". If you have an endpoint sending message to another ednpoint, the "To" field makes sense. With topics and subscriptions, you broadcast a message, and subscriptions filter those out. Therefore no 1 to 1 mapping and clear destination. The approach you're taking is correct. You can also use custom properties (headers).

Comment: @Sean Thanks again for the additional insight .   I took your advice  from yesterday and it's working great.